# iTextSharp creates a damaged .pdf file

Tags: pdf, itext

I am writing a "combine" .pdf file application.  The .pdf file that I generate with the code below results in a .pdf file that can not be opened by Adobe.  This is the code I am executing:

```
 Dim doc_fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Dim document_path = "C:\pdffilesfolder\"
 Dim document_folder = doc_fs.GetFolder(document_path)

 Dim dateArray() As String
 dateArray = lblDateToPrint.Text.Split("/")   'lblDateToPrint.Text contains "3/21/2017"
 If Val(dateArray(0)) < 10 Then
    dateArray(0) = "0" & dateArray(0)
 End If
 If Val(dateArray(1)) < 10 Then
    dateArray(1) = "0" & dateArray(1)
 End If

 Dim outFile as string = document_path & "\confirms_" & dateArray(2) & "_" & dateArray(0) & "_" & dateArray(1) & ".pdf"     
 Dim document = New Document
 Dim writer As PdfCopy = New PdfCopy(document, New FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create))
 document.Open()


 Dim fileOnServer As String = ""
 Dim fileOnServerDate As String = ""

 For Each item In document_folder.Files
      fileOnServer = item.path
      Dim reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(fileOnServer)
      writer.AddDocument(reader)
      reader.Close()
 Next
```

I have attached the 2 .pdf files that I am using as input as well as the resulting .pdf file (even through Adobe says it can not be opened).

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Jonathan

Comment: The 2 source files can be found here: 
https://www.accurecord-direct.com/pdffiles/confirms/8462_C05i8y456t2i0k0z0p0u1sevke0nwdqvkudg20170321113741.pdf
 and https://www.accurecord-direct.com/PDFFILES/Confirms/VSTA_C05s7q717a7x707x7a7o7pvety4lzxw3ucog20170321125034.pdf

Comment: and the resulting file can be found here: https://www.accurecord-direct.com/PDFFILES/Confirms/confirms_2017_03_21.pdf

Comment: I don't see you eventually closing the document. Did you merely forget to copy&paste? Or do you actually not close it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to eventually close the `Document document`:

```
Dim document = New Document
Dim writer As PdfCopy = New PdfCopy(document, New FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create))
document.Open()

Dim fileOnServer As String = ""
Dim fileOnServerDate As String = ""

For Each item In document_folder.Files
    fileOnServer = item.path
    Dim reader As PdfReader = New PdfReader(fileOnServer)
    writer.AddDocument(reader)
    reader.Close()
Next

document.Close() ' Don't forget to close the document!
```

Comment: You are right.  I forgot to close the document.  Unfortunately, after adding that line of code, the resulting .pdf file is still not valid.

Comment: @Jonathan please share a result file created with closing.

Comment: Here is a link to the resulting file: accurecord-direct.com/PDFFILES/Confirms/confirms_2017_03_21.‌​pdf

Comment: That link requires username and password.

Comment: Or do you mean the same file you shared yesterday in a comment to your question? It has the same name at least. But you shared that *before* adding the `Close` call.

Comment: It's the same file.  I wanted to attach it to this thread but I don't know how.  I created a bitly for it but stack overflow won't allow me to post a link to that.  I'll continue to play with this and do further research on the web to try to resolve it.  Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @JonathanSmall *"It's the same file."* - As you created that file *before* adding the `Close` call to your code, it is of no help for determining what still goes wrong *since* adding that `Close` call. The old file simply was cut off, a typical symptom of a missing `Close` call or an exception; but you have now added the `Close` call and you surely would have told us if some exception occured.

Comment: @mki You're right!  I reset my code and deleted my resulting file and re-ran the code with the close command.  The resulting .pdf file was generated correctly!  Thank you so much!